# 2 tables with the same named columns doesnot work

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table and both have 1 field named `personID`, in one table it auto-increment and I want to write it to another table. it happens on the same page. I generate person id and then trying to call using select and write in another but it doesn't work. please help me .

The PHP code that does not work looks like this:

```
$result2 = mysql_query ("
    INSERT INTO 'topics' ('personID') 
        SELECT personID 
        FROM persons 
        WHERE personID = 1
");
```

Comment: Why not use aliases for both the tables?

Comment: I am not very familiar with mysql, but isn't your query just wrong?

Comment: [Please, stop using mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1238019) in new code, they are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Instead of, have a look on [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), and use [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

You are telling the database to insert PersonID from second table to you first table where PersonID in second table is 1.

That is equivalent to saying `Insert 1 into first table table`.

```
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO topics (personID) VALUES (1)");  // equivalent to your query.
```

Comment: Quotes removed, Thanks.

Comment: The quotes are his only problem, see the example code above :)

Comment: Nope. That's an overkill. Look at the question again, that sub query is not even needed

Comment: Oh, I agree that it's not needed - but it WILL work. Besides, he might want to copy more columns along rather than just the ID.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with the query, except you are using single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO topics (personID) 
SELECT personID FROM persons where personID = 1
```

If you are using a reserved word in MySQL, you should use a backtick ` (normally next to the 1 on a keyboard) to encompass the name.

See following example:

```
mysql> select * from test1;
+------+-------+
| id   | varry |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaa   |
+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)

mysql> select * from test2;
+------+-------+-------+
| id   | barry | third |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 | ccc   |  NULL |
| NULL | d     |     1 |
| NULL | d     |     2 |
| NULL | d     |     3 |
+------+-------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 (id) select id from test2 where barry='ccc';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into test1 ('id') select 'id' from test2 where barry='ccc';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id')
 select 'id' from test2 where barry='ccc'' at line 1
mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

After Calling  insert inside auto increment table just do this

```
$id = mysql_insert_id ();
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO 'topics' (personId) VALUES ('$id')");
```

And that's all

Answer (score 0):

In your query you always select person with `personID = 1`. Does it exist?
If you insert person in transaction, make sure the transaction is committed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify table.columnName.

```
$result2 = mysql_query ("
INSERT INTO topics (topics.personID) 
    SELECT personID 
    FROM persons 
    WHERE persons.personID = 1
");
```